# .net core mvc get controller method return the downloading file , but not working?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I have `List<model>` and I convert to JSON in Javascript and when I click button call controller method
and pass paramater like this :

```
$('#exceldownload').click(function(){

    var json = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ReportListModel,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    json = JSON.stringify(json);


    window.location = "@Url.Action("ReportExcel","Report")?model="+json+"";

});
```

And Controller Code :

```
public FileResult ReportExcel(string model)
        {
            var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReportListModel>>(model);
            if (b.Count == 0)
            {
                return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("empty"), "text/plain", "empty");
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable table = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b), (typeof(DataTable)));

                using (var excelPack = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    var ws = excelPack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WriteTest");
                    ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(table, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light8);
                    var FileBytesArray = excelPack.GetAsByteArray();
                    return File(FileBytesArray, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I click button and getting like this :

This site can't be reached,
Localhost refused to connect,
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I want to when I click button download excel file.

Comment: I think Send request url wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's crashing at this line:

```
window.location = "@Url.Action("ReportExcel","Report")?model="+json+"";
```

Change it to

```
window.location = @Url.Action("ReportExcel","Report") + "?model="+json+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the ASP.NET code. Probably an internal server error occurs.

Comment: I tried debug mode controller method but this method not working debug mode. when i click button but never enters method.

Comment: okay then it looks like the method actually is never called. Maybe change "@Url.Action("ReportExcel","Report")?model="+json+"" to '@Url.Action("ReportExcel","Report")?model='+json